# Netbeans C/C++ on Linux "step in to" Linux C runtime code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, netbeans

When debugging C/C++ code with netbeans on Linux, is it possible to "step in to" the native C runtime library (to see source code for malloc() etc), just like Visual Studio can on Windows?

If not, can any Linux IDEs?

Comment: Does Virual Studio show the source code of `malloc`?!

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` and many functions have compiler's specific implementation. Usually you can 't access to the source code of them in this way. For example in gcc/g++, `malloc` is declared in `<cstdlib>` and implemented as a external function in `.dll` file.

In Visual Studio, you can go through some declarations and see some weird codes, but they are just some high-level codes to invoke the *real* `malloc`. You can not see the real implementation of `malloc`.

For example, in my test after step into `malloc`, I saw below code which is just an call to an internal function, and so on... finally you will see nothing:

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP void * __cdecl malloc (
        size_t nSize
        )
{
        void *res = _nh_malloc_dbg(nSize, _newmode, _NORMAL_BLOCK, NULL, 0);

        RTCCALLBACK(_RTC_Allocate_hook, (res, nSize, 0));

        return res;
}
```

Comment: This does not look like Linux `malloc`!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Actually it's MinGW's `malloc`. It's just an example to say my point.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the `libc6-dbg` (or `libc-dbg`) package, if on Debian or Ubuntu (or derived) distribution.

Then use the [set debug-file-directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html) command of `gdb`

And since Linux is free software, you can study the source code of `malloc`; your distribution is probably used some patched variant of [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/); you might also look into [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/), whose source code seems more readable to me.

FWIW, [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is certainly using syscalls like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), etc...

And on many distributions you can rebuild packaged software from source code (e.g. with `apt-build`...)

<sup>But if you are a newbie, I don't recommend rebuilding `libc` because it is the central piece of almost all applications!</sup>